# django MultiValueDictKeyError error at request.FILES['file']

Tags: django, django-views

I am new to python/django and unable to figure out the issue. The requirement is to upload a csv file to load the data into the database.

I have a custom model for users where the data needs to be loaded. Error seems to be occurring at 
csv_file = request.FILES['file']

Error-

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /upload-csv/ 'file'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload-csv/
Django Version: 2.2.2
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    
'file'
Exception Location: D:\djreact\backend\env\lib\site-    packages\django\utils\datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 80
Python Executable:  D:\djreact\backend\env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['D:\\djreact\\backend\\src',
 'D:\\djreact\\backend\\env\\Scripts\\python37.zip',
 'D:\\djreact\\backend\\env\\DLLs',
 'D:\\djreact\\backend\\env\\lib',
 'D:\\djreact\\backend\\env\\Scripts',
 'd:\\python\\python37\\Lib',
 'd:\\python\\python37\\DLLs',
 'D:\\djreact\\backend\\env',
 'D:\\djreact\\backend\\env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 2 Jul 2019 12:49:52 +0000
```

View.py -

```
def user_upload(request):
template="user_upload.html"
prompt = {
    'order': 'order of csv should be first_name, last_name, email'
}
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, template, prompt)

csv_file = request.FILES['file']

data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
    _, created =  User.Objects.update_or_create(
    first_name = column[0],
    last_name = column[1],
    email = column[2]
    )
return render(request, template)
```

template - user_upload.html

```
{% if messages %} {% for message in messages %}
<div>
    <strong>{{message|safe}}</strong>
</div>
{% endfor %} {% else %} {{order}}
<form method="post" encrypt="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    <label> Upload a file </label>
    <input type="file" name='file'>
    </br>
        <button type="submit"> Upload</button>
</form>
{% endif %}
```

Model

```
class DepUser(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)    
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    emailVerifCode = models.CharField(null = True,blank=True, max_length=30)
```

Answer (score 1):

The attribute in the form element should be `enctype`, not `encrypt`.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. yes this did resole the issue